# Cómo utilizar el comando for en cpp

Tags: python, c++

soy nuevo en esto de programación, apenas inicié este semestre y ando viendo c++ y python. Hoy mi maestro nos dejó para practicar pasar el código que hicimos en python a C++, pero no entiendo bien cómo se hace. Este código lo desarrollé en python:

```
    repetir = "S"
while repetir.upper() == "S":
        numero = -1
        while numero <= 0:
            numero = int(input("Proporcione número entero y positivo: "))
            if numero <= 0:
                print("Valor inválido")
        suma = 0
        print("Los divisores de ", numero, " son:")
        print("")
        for divisor in range(1, numero, 1):
            if numero % divisor == 0: #división cero provoca error
                suma += divisor
                print (divisor)
        print("")
        if suma > numero:
            print("El número ", numero, " es superabundante pues sus divisores suman ", suma)
        elif suma < numero:
            print("El número ", numero, " es deficiente pues sus divisores suman ", suma)
        else:
            print("El número ", numero, " es perfecto pues sus divisores suman ", suma)
        repetir = input("¿Desea evaluar otro número? S/N ")
```

Pero mi duda es que el ciclo for que se muestra en el código de arriba no sé como plantearlo en for de c++, esto es lo que llevo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char repetir = 'S';
    int numero;
    float divisor, suma;
    do{
        numero = -1
        while (numero <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Proporcione el número entero y positivo: " << endl;
            cin >> numero;
            if (numero <= 0)
            {
                cout << "Valor inválido" << endl;
            }
        suma = 0;
        cout << "Los divisores de " << numero << " son: " << endl;
        for(float divisor; )
        }
        
    } while (toupper(repetir) == 'S');

    return 0;
}
```

Si pudieran resolver mi pregunta se agradecería mucho, gracias.

Comment: Lo que tu quieres es un tutorial. En resumen es para los for normales: `for (inicializacion; condicion; incrementos)`. Si vas a usar un contenedor con `begin()` y `end()` definidos, puedes usar: `for (auto& c : contenedor)`

Answer (score 2):

Primero debemos aclarar que `for` no es un comando, es una [estructura de control](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estructuras_de_control%3E). Una vez aclarado eso, hay que distinguir dos tipos de `for` en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

- **El `for` tradicional**: ejecuta diferentes instrucciones para inicializar datos, modificar valores y decidir si finalizar.
- **El `for` de rango**: itera sobre un rango de valores de una colección de datos.

---

El `for` tradicional se compone de inicialización(es), condición de salida y operación.

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
//   ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^  ^^^
//       \         \      \________________________ Operación.
//        \         \__________ Condición de salida.
//         \____ Inicialización.
```

Pero todos los componentes son opcionales:

```
for (;;) // Un for válido, sin inicialización, condición de salida ni operación. Es infinito.
```

Y puede ser muy complejo:

- La inicialización puede definir múltiples variables, siempre y cuando todas ellas sean del mismo tipo.
- La condición de salida puede ser una expresión tan compleja como sea necesaria, siempre y cuando pueda evaluarse como verdadera o falsa.
- La operación puede contener múltiples operaciones separadas por coma.

El `for` de rango se compone de iterador y colección.

```
int valores[100]{};
for (int i : valores)
//   ^^^^^   ^^^^^^^
//      \        \_____ Colección de datos.
//       \____ Iterador.
```

Funciona para cualquier dato para el que las llamadas `std::begin(colección)` y `std::end(colección)` sean válidas y devuelvan un objeto que sea incrementable (que contenga el operador `++`) y que sea des-referenciable (que contenga el operador unario `*`).

Las opciones de personalización caen todas en el iterador, el cuál puede ser:

- Una copia de los valores: `for (tipo iterador : colección)`.
- Una referencia a los valores: `for (tipo &iterador : colección)`.
- Una referencia de sólo lectura a los valores: `for (const tipo &iterador : colección)`.

Answer (score 0):

te puedo dar el funcionamiento del for que de hecho para mi es mucho mas sencillo de entender que el for de python esta es la sintaxis

```
for(iterador = inicializacion ; iterador operador logico tamaño; avance del iterador){
             codigo
}
```

Como ejemplo tendriamos que

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
       cout << "Hola soy la vuelta numero" << i << endl;
 }
```

como vemos i esta inicializado en 0 es, el bucle se repetirá hasta que i deje de ser mayor que 10 es decir hasta el 9 pero se repetirán 10 veces ya que el iterador empieza con 0, y al final i++ indica que cuando se acabe de ejecutar el código dentro del for a i se le sumara 1  i++ es lo mismo que decir i = i + 1 y en cada vuelta se ira imprimiendo el codigo

Dentro en el codigo tenemos que se imprimira el string "Hola esta es la vuelta numero" y seguido imprimiremos el iterador que nos dara como resultado:

```
Hola esta es la vuelta numero 0
Hola esta es la vuelta numero 1
Hola esta es la vuelta numero 2
Hola esta es la vuelta numero 3
```

Espero haberte ayudado.